# Flutter BoringSSL-GRPC unable to install

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoa, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to install the package: `cloud_firestore` and am getting an error when running the pod install when installing the dependency `BoringSSL-GRPC`.
Is it possible for me to install the dependency another way and reference it/is there another issue that I am missing. Thank you in advance to anyone who can help!

```
    Downloading dependencies

    -> Installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.3)
     > Git download
     > Git download
         $ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/google/boringssl.git /var/folders/2g/mfqr5f5148nd_w6g9f1g72p80000gn/T/d20200505-3960-17lhqyp --template=

    [!] Error installing BoringSSL-GRPC
    [!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/google/boringssl.git /var/folders/2g/mfqr5f5148nd_w6g9f1g72p80000gn/T/d20200505-3960-17lhqyp --template=

    Cloning into '/var/folders/2g/mfqr5f5148nd_w6g9f1g72p80000gn/T/d20200505-3960-17lhqyp'...
    error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
    fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
    fatal: early EOF
    fatal: index-pack failed

    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:142:in `rescue in execute_command'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:139:in `execute_command'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.3.0/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:154:in `block in executable'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.3.0/lib/cocoapods-downloader/git.rb:79:in `block in clone'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:173:in `block in ui_sub_action'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:172:in `ui_sub_action'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.3.0/lib/cocoapods-downloader/git.rb:77:in `clone'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.3.0/lib/cocoapods-downloader/git.rb:45:in `download!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.3.0/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:82:in `block in download'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:157:in `block in ui_action'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:156:in `ui_action'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.3.0/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:80:in `download'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:108:in `download_source'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:75:in `download_request'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:171:in `download'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:154:in `block in uncached_pod'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:181:in `in_tmpdir'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:153:in `uncached_pod'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:33:in `download_pod'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:42:in `download'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:117:in `download_source'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:69:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:557:in `install_source_of_pod'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:508:in `block (2 levels) in install_pod_sources'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:86:in `titled_section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:507:in `block in install_pod_sources'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:490:in `each'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:490:in `install_pod_sources'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:249:in `block in download_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:248:in `download_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:157:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
         Cloning into '/var/folders/2g/mfqr5f5148nd_w6g9f1g72p80000gn/T/d20200505-3960-17lhqyp'...
         error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
         fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
         fatal: early EOF
         fatal: index-pack failed

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
```

[image: Error]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please do not show pictures of text.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: Cocoapods failed in the git clone step. I am not sure what's the root cause on your system, but I would suggest you run the pod install command with --verbose flag, see what exactly the command is, and try to run it outside of Cocoapods to debug.

Comment: I've tried following command on terminal, but also failed to install.
    git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000  
    git config --global http.lowSpeedLimit 0   
    git config --global http.lowSpeedTime 999999

Could you find any solution?

Comment: I could fix this issue by Muhamad Jalal's answer.

Comment: is this the first time you ran the app or it was running before and then it broke?

Answer (score 5):

I tried all many ways and none of them work. Then, I reboot my machine. And it works. Don't understand the reason !

Answer (score 3):

Change all firebase dependencies I use to this versions solve my problem

```
 firebase_messaging: ^10.0.2
 firebase_auth: ^1.4.1
 cloud_firestore: ^2.2.1
 firebase_storage: ^8.1.3
 firebase_core: ^1.3.0
```

Comment: Installing Boringssl 0.0.7 was worked with old versions until 2021.4, but suddenly I couldn't install it again anymore from last month.
I've tried with all other answers, but couldn't fix this issue in my case.
Today I found your answer and fixed my issue.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @persec10000 Happy to know, Keep it up Bro.

Comment: I tried these same version numbers but this had no effect, still facing this issue. Even if it would have solved the issue, this is now one year old and I want to use more recent versions

Comment: which Flutter version do you use?

Answer (score 3):

I got a slightly different error. I also got `gunzip: (stdin): unexpected end of file` but I saw a few hundred lines of base64 data above it.

I'm on OSX and it turns out that I have gnu coreutils installed which has a base64 version wasn't compatible to what was downloaded. I solved it by:

```
brew uninstall coreutils
```

Note: I opened a bounty on this question to no avail, and then I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72500565/119861).

Comment: This was a lifesaver! I had to go a step further and remove my modified PATH pointing to `/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin` and uninstall the x86_64 brew coreutils installation.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem. Leaving solution here for anyone who it might help.

This is hard to believe. I root caused this issue to a wired ethernet adapter I was using. wifi and two other wired ethernet adapters worked.

Note that ethernet adapter seemed to work fine otherwise. The git clone worked fine from the command line, the issue only surfaced when ruby Process.spawn executed it!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to solve the issue:

1. flutter clean
2. removed pod lock file
3. removed pubspec.lock
4. flutter pub get
5. pod install

Answer (score 0):

This method has worked for me.

Restart your terminal/code editor by killing and closing it then relaunch.

```
cd your-project-dir

cd ios
```

run

> pod install

This will download all the dependencies. It might take some bit of time so ensure to wait.

```
NB: Ensure to have stable internet.
```

Comment: i tried this but instead i ran pod update, all libraries are up to date yet it still gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

## I solved it by simply by doing:

1. Remove all the pods and add `BoringSSL-GRPC`:

#### Podfile

```rb
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'XXXXX' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'BoringSSL-GRPC'
end
```

2. Execute (bash) `pod install --repo-update`
3. Remove the `pod 'BoringSSL-GRPC'` and add again the other libraries

#### Podfile

```
...
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'Firebase/Functions'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift', '~> 7.9-beta'
...
```

Comment: This is also not working on my side. Step No2 ( pod install --repo-update ) has the same issue.

Comment: having the same issue, already step 2 (only installing boring ssl without anything else) is triggering this error for me

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version of flutter since most of the packages has switched to flutter3. Try deleting Podfile.lock, Pods directory, .symlinks directory and runner.xcworkspace file. Next run `cd ios` and then from the ios path run `pod install --repo-update`. If that doesn't work, try invalidating cache and restarting IDE. If that fails too try `flutter pub cache clean`. Please note that it will delete all your pub cache so you may have to run pub get on all projects.

Comment: thanks for providing an answer (actually the only one since I opened the bounty), but this also doesn't work for me. I tried also the `pub cache clean` and then `pub get`, but I still run into the same error: "base64: invalid input -- gunzip: (stdin): unexpected end of file"

Comment: Add the cloud firestore version as any in pubspec.yaml. delete pubspec.lock run pub get. Delete podfile.lock and then run pod install --repo-update and try once please

Comment: I tried with the any version, still the same error. I didn't have the podfile.lock file though. Probably because pod install never worked.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

> - Using **VPN** solved the issue and downloaded pods with no issue.
> - Does anyone possess insights into the specific root cause of this matter?

---

**Tried Approces**

I have tried all the solutions, but none of them worked for me, including...

> - Clean Up
> - Deleting the Pod.lock file
> - Updating brew and CocoaPods, followed by a clean installation
> - Updating buffer size
> - Configuring `git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same issue despite trying numerous solutions.
Surprisingly, the resolution came unexpectedly after I changed my WiFi network's name. This action, although seemingly unrelated, resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Quiting VPN solved this issue 
I don't know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

in your podfile
paste this line of code in your target 'Runner' do :

pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '8.15.0'
note!:  tag => '8.15.0' should be updated to the latest version).

it should look like this to avoid any interruption with your podfile setup

```
target 'Runner' do

  use_frameworks!

  use_modular_headers!
  
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '10.20.0'

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths

  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was due to incompatibility as I installed `node_modules` with a prior version of node which caused the issue when installing pods, especially with `BoringSSL-GRPC` and `gRPC-Core` pods. I upgraded my node version to v20 LTS and reinstalled `node_modules` and then reinstalled pods with `pod install --repo-update` and everything went smooth.