iOS Folder recreate in Flutter Project
Before I was using Windows, but now I've switched to MacOS. When I run the project, it's giving me the error:
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
         Cloning into
         '/var/folders/z3/233llhh52fl54rmbpry1zslw0000gn/T/d20240401-33707-a6wecd'...
         error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 5 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
         error: 5444 bytes of body are still expected
         fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
         fatal: early EOF
         fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

    [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `12.0` on target `Runner` because
    no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See
    `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Error: Error running pod install

I've tried multiple ways, but the pod install is always failing.

try this answer => https://stackoverflow.com/a/64752033/18645340

not working, it fails at Installing BoringSSL-GRPC

do you use firebase? If so try an answer here taht mentions the versions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61603856/flutter-boringssl-grpc-unable-to-install

@ClevinoAlrin thanks a lot, restarting machine worked for me
